# Navigate in React-Native + Redux using React-Navigation between Nested Navigators

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I figured out how react-navigation works in general from the official docs. However, I get really confused when I have to deal with Nested Navigators especially in Big Apps.

This is the Navigation Structure I have implemented in my app.

- RootNavigation (Stack Navigator)

  - Splash Screen -> Default Screen
  - Login Screen
  - SignUp Screen
  - Main (Stack Navigator)

    - Camera (Stack Navigator)

      - Camera Screen
      - Preview Screen
    - Home (Tab Navigator) -> Default Screen

      - Posts (Stack Navigator)
            - All Posts Screen -> Default Screen
            - Show Comments Post Screen
      - // Rest are similar to Posts (Stack Navigator)

Now when I try to navigate from Splash Screen to Home checking if user is logged in this is how I try to do it -> `this.props.navigation.navigate ({routeName: 'RootScreenFour'})`

The problem I am facing is how to navigate from All Posts Screen to Camera Screen

I tried this -> `this.props.navigation.navigate ({routeName: 'CameraScreen'})`. But nothing happens.

I even connected the app to redux. This is my config:

```
class Root extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        if (Platform.OS !== 'android') return;
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
            const { dispatch } = this.props;
            dispatch({ type: 'Navigation/BACK' });
            return true
        })
    }

    // when the app is closed, remove the event listener
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }

    render() {
        // slap the navigation helpers on (critical step)
        const { dispatch, rootNavState } = this.props;
        const navigation = addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch,
            state: rootNavState
        });
        return (
                <RootNavigationStack
                navigation={navigation} />
        )
    }
}
```

This is Root Config File:

```
    const routeConfiguration = {
        RootScreenOne: {
            screen: Splash,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: false
            }
        },
        RootScreenTwo: {
            screen: Signup,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: false
            }
        },
        RootScreenThree: {
            screen: Login,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: false
            }
        },
        RootScreenFour: {
            screen: Main,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: false
            }
        }
    };

// going to disable the header for now
const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'RootScreenOne'
};

export default RootNavigationStack = StackNavigator(routeConfiguration, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
```

My Main Config:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    MainScreenOne: {
        screen: CameraTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    },
    MainScreenTwo: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    }
};

// going to disable the header for now
const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'MainScreenTwo'
};

export default MainNavigationStack = StackNavigator(routeConfiguration, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
```

Camera Config:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    CameraScreenOne: {
        screen: Camera,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    },
    CameraScreenTwo: {
        screen: Preview,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    }
};

// going to disable the header for now
const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'CameraScreenOne'
};

export default CameraTabNavigationStack = StackNavigator(routeConfiguration, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
```

The Rest are similar no point in showing in config.

This is how I attatched my redux:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = RootNavigationStack.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.init());

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    let nextState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GO_TO_CAMERA': {
         //   NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'CameraScreenOne' });
            nextState = RootNavigationStack.router.getStateForAction(MainNavigationStack.router.getActionForPathAndParams('MainScreenOne'));

//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//This breaks the app. NavigationActions.navigate also does not work
            break;
        }

        default: {
            nextState = RootNavigationStack.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
            break;
        }
    }

    return nextState || state
}
```

If someone could help me out. How do I navigate in deep nested navigators from one screen to another?

**UPDATE:**
Update my redux case to below

```
case 'GO_TO_CAMERA': {
            nextState = RootNavigationStack.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'CameraScreen'}));
            break;
        }
```

This broke the app as well. It goes into a loop of going and coming back from the camera screen.

Comment: Here is an article for react-navigation and redux along with a github repo for various scenarios https://hackernoon.com/a-comprehensive-guide-for-integrating-react-navigation-with-redux-including-authentication-flow-cb7b90611adf